# The “Feel” of the Various Genders of German Nouns

Tags: standard-german

As a native German speaker, how accurately can you guess the gender of a noun you don’t know (or whose definition you know, but whose gender you don’t)? For more common nouns, how often do you forget their gender? To you, are there any significant commonalities in the “feel” of the words of the different genders? Maybe how they’re spoken, what they connotate for you emotionally, temporally, spatially, etc.?

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a duplicate since the question isn't about new words, it's about unknown words.

Comment: @DavidVogt: the answers should be pretty much the same. Most of the question would be *primarily opinion based* anyway (I usually prefer dupe over other close reasons).

Comment: @DavidVogt Agree with Takkat - *new* also includes *new to you* = unknown.

Comment: Most new German nouns are new compounds. They inherit their gender from the last component. For the very small remainder, I go for the ending syllable and assume the same gender as the majority of words with the same nominative ending.